# как создать из обычного событие сетевое

Tags: c#, unity3d

когда подключаюсь по сети.мой персонаж выпускает ракету а персонаж который подключается не видит как я выпускаю ракету

Этот скрипт привязан к персонажу

```
public GameObject Rocket;

//ракеты спаунятся только у мастера
if (photonView.isMine)
{
//вызываем объект ракету и придаем ей силу
Instantiate(Rocket, transform.position + transform.forward * 2, transform.rotation);
}
```

Этот скрипт привязан к ракете

```
public int power;

void Start () 
{
gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * power);
}
```

Comment: раз уж используется photon(используется же?) то нужно искать информацию о событиях в документации самого фотона ( https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/bolt/current/reference/events ). И тем более нужно указывать какой библиотекой ты собираешся пользоватся для этого, если уж собираешся. Это делает возможность того что тебе ответят здесь хоть сколь-нибудь вероятной.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что указано недостаточно информации что бы ответить обьективно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше действительно указать, что используете `Photon` - а то приходится догадываться из самого кода, где у вас есть свойство `PhotonView.IsMine`

Сделать метод `Instantiate` сетевым достаточно просто - в скрипте, который привязан к персонажу, заменяем метод `Instantiate(Объект для спауна, позиция, поворот) на сетевое` `PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Имя объекта для спауна", позиция, поворот, группа (=0))`

Объект с именем для спауна должен находится в папке `Assets/Resources`, и на нем должен быть навешан компонент `PhotonView`. Тогда всё получится и объект будет появляться у всех игроков в комнате.

Итоговый код для персонажа( у ракеты ничего менять не надо, только `PhotonView` навешать и в ресурсы префаб засунуть)

```
//ракеты спаунятся только у мастера
if (photonView.isMine)
{
//вызываем объект ракету и придаем ей силу
PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Rocket", transform.position + transform.forward * 2, transform.rotation,0);
}
```